# Authentic Asian Sweet & Sour Sauce - Recipe

Tags: sauce

Although its a well known fact that the Sweet & Sour sauce we have come to expect is not really an authentic sauce served in Asia, its one that we have come to love in North America. The problem is sourcing that perfect recipe. 
Although I live in the Asian capital of British Columbia and have an extended network of colleagues in the food industry, I am still stumped and cant find the recipe for this sauce. There are plenty of hacks available online, but still nothing that compares.
If there is anyone with an Asian culinary background that is willing to post and share a recipe for this sauce, I would truly appreciate it if they could post it here.
Thank you & kind regards in advance.

Mark

Comment: Thanks for your question. Unfortunately, we are not a recipe sharing site.  If you can edit your question to inquire about technique, or some other aspect about Asian sweet and sour sauce (Asia encompasses a lot of cultures!), that might be answerable.  As currently posed, your question will likely be closed.

Comment: @moscafj- We don't allow recipes because they are opinion based and there is no right answer. In this case ChefSwan is looking for a very specific, canonical, preparation. In my opinion this would make the question fall under restaurant mimicry rather than a generic recipe request. That said, the question does not give any specifics to describe the sauce that they are looking for. With very specific details about the sauce I think this question is answerable.

Comment: @Sobachatina a request for "Asian sweet and sour sauce" might be the epitome of opinion based.  As I point out, Asia is big place with many cultures. Further, in my opinion there is a fine line between the restaurant mimicry category and recipe requests.  ...maybe a discussion for meta...

Comment: @Sobachatina...actually, this is clearly spelled out here:https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/what-are-restaurant-mimicry-questions

Comment: @moscafj- The second bullet point in Rumtscho's answer would cover this question. I agree that the problem is the phrase "Asian sweet and sour sauce" instead of giving us a specific description of the common preparation. Still- it's not a recipe request problem- they aren't asking for any recipe. They're asking for a specific recipe with a very poor description of it.

Comment: "Asian sweet and sour sauce" is not asking for any sauce from anywhere in Asia- it's asking about a particular sauce that the asker is very familiar with and encounters in many restaurants. I agree with you that the question, as it is now, is not answerable. However- if ChefSwan described well enough that sauce then it would be answerable.

Comment: @Sobachatina to make it clear: the question would need both a better description, and the OP's understanding that they have to do the reverse engineering job themselves, and we are just going to give pointers. If the question describes the question better, but the expectation is still for a recipe, it is not really a question for us.

Answer (score 1):

You're only going to get an approximate answer to this because there isn't "one sauce" that is sweet and sour, even in Vancouver.  Instead, there are [multiple sauces that fit that description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_and_sour), having both acid and sugar in them.  Common ingredients include any of white sugar, brown sugar, honey, vinegar (of several kinds), soy sauce, lemon juice, plum puree, ginger, ketchup, various sour fruits, and spices.

[This blog](https://www.chinasichuanfood.com/chinese-sweet-and-sour-sauce/) has multiple recipes for sweet-and-sour sauces from Sichuan, which might suit what you're looking for.